# Object consisting of two objects

Tags: c#

I have a class `Loan`:

```
public class Loan
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string PropertyAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    //etc..
}
```

And a class `Client`:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    // etc..
}
```

I need a `ClientWithLoan` object, as there is no multiple inheritance in C# what would be the correct pattern for that?

Comment: you can create new class  `ClientWithLoan`  with two proprieties `Client` and `Loan`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Comment: [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: you could also create an interface for the `Client` and `ClientWithLoan`, you can make `Client` an `abstract`. There are many ways - which one is 'correct' depends on your use case.

Comment: Can one client have several loans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

### Distinct class

If a `ClientWithLoan` is to be a distinct type from a `Client` then you could do it this way:

```
class ClientWithLoan : Client
{
    public Loan Loan { get; set; }
}
```

You might also want to include some validation:

```
class ClientWithLoan : Client
{
    protected Loan _loan;

    public Loan Loan 
    { 
        get { return _loan; }
        set
        {
            if (value.ClientID != this.ID) throw ArgumentException();
            _loan = value;
        }
    }
}
```

### Keep what you have

Just add a `Loan` property to your Client class, and leave it null if that particular client has no loan.

```
public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Loan Loan { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you require multiple inheritance in a language with single inheritance, using interfaces usually solves the issue.

You could do this in this way:

```
public interface ILoan
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string PropertyAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    //etc..
}

public interface IClient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    // etc..
}

public interface IClientWithLoan: IClient, ILoan
{
}

public sealed class ClientWithLoan: IClientWithLoan
{
    // here place the real implementation
}
```

This approach gives you the flexibility you ask.